# Как задать выходы нейронной сети

Tags: python

Имеется нейронная сеть, которая классифицирует объекты на изображении (два класса). Должно быть два выхода: Для тренировочных изображений имеется четыре координаты квадрата, в котором находится изображение на фотографии. Нужно иметь 1 выход на класс и четыре выхода на координаты квадрата (нормализованные к единице). Куда подаются данные о классе. Куда нужно записывать данные о координатах. Как можно вывести данные о координатах Буду благодарен, если подскажете ответ на один из вопросов: Как задавать выходы? Как использовать обученную сеть, чтобы на фото отображался класс (1 или ноль)?
Архитектура сети: Слой свертки, размер ядра 3х3, количество карт признаков - 32 шт., функция активации ReLU. Слой подвыборки, выбор максимального значения из квадрата 2х2. Слой свертки, размер ядра 3х3, количество карт признаков - 32 шт., функ. Слой свертки, размер ядра 3х3, количество карт признаков - 64 шт., функция активации ReLU. Слой подвыборки, выбор максимального значения из квадрата 2х2. Слой преобразования из двумерного в одномерное представление. Полносвязный слой, 64 нейрона, функция активации ReLU. Слой Dropout. Выходной слой, 1 нейрон, функция активации sigmoid. Слои с 1 по 6 используются для выделения важных признаков в изображении, а слои с 7 по 10 - для классификации.

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense

img_width, img_height = 50, 50
input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)
epochs = 1
batch_size = 16

nb_train_samples = len(os.listdir(train_dir + "/cat")) +     len(os.listdir(train_dir + "/dog"))
nb_validation_samples = len(os.listdir(val_dir + "/cat")) + len(os.listdir(val_dir + "/dog"))
nb_test_samples = len(os.listdir(test_dir + "/cat")) + len(os.listdir(test_dir + "/dog"))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy'])
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

val_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    val_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=val_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
scores = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, nb_test_samples // batch_size)
```

Comment: Не уверен, что это имеет смысл делать в одной сетке. И вообще если у вас будет соотношение сторон, то получить из него класс можно будет одной строкой кода. Если это не отдельные задачи, которые должны работать друг без друга, то, думаю, надо делать один выход и решать задачу регрессии, соответственно, там не сигмоид на выходе будет, и прочие параметры надо смотреть от регрессии, я не помню честно говоря, что там должно быть, надо смотреть.

Comment: @CrazyElf кроме меток классов 1 и 0. Для тренировочных изображений имеется четыре координаты квадрата, в котором находится изображение на фотографии. Нужно иметь 1 выход на класс и четыре выхода на координаты квадрата (нормализованные к единице). В итоге на тестовых изображениях нужно нарисовать квадрат

Comment: А, да, тренировочные данные же с классами, что-то я не сообразил. Надо ждать кого-то, кто нормально разбирается в нейросетях, я пас )